# How to estimate? "simple" Nonlinear Regression + Parameter Constraints + AR residuals

Tags: nls, nonlinear-optimization, nlme, non-linear-regression

I am new to this site so please bear with me. I want to 
the nonlinear model as shown in the link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNpWt.png by imposing constraints on the parameters a>0 and b>0 and gamma1 in [0,1].

In the nonlinear model [1] independent variable is x(t) and dependent are R(t), F(t) and ξ(t) is the error term.

An example of the dataset can be shown here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Vf0j.png  68 rows of time series

To estimate the nonlinear regression I use the nls() function with no problem as shown below:

**NLM1**  = **nls(**Xt ~ (a*Rt-b*Ft)/(1-gamma1*Rt), start = list(a = 10, b = 10, lamda = 0.5**)**,algorithm = "port", lower=c(0,0,0),upper=c(Inf,Inf,1),data = temp2)

I want to estimate NLM1 with allowing for also an AR(1) on the residuals.

Basically I want the same procedure as we go from lm() to gls(). My problem is that in the gnls() function I dont know how to put contraints for the model parameters a, b, gamma1 and the model estimates wrong values for them.

nls() has the option for lower and upper bounds. I cant do the same on gnls()

In the gnls(): I need to add the contraints something like as in nls() lower=c(0,0,0),upper=c(Inf,Inf,1)

NLM1_AR1 = gnls( model = Xt ~ (a*Rt-b*Ft)/(1-gamma1*Rt), data = temp2, start = list(a =13, b = 10, lamda = 0.5),correlation = corARMA(p = 1))

Does any1 know the solution on how to do it?

Thank you